# Eclipse java project missing plugins

Tags: java, eclipse

I am transferring my projects from an XP system to a Windows 8.1 system.
On my XP, I used Eclipse Juno with Window Builder and JavaFx.
I have now installed the latest Eclipse (Java Mars 64bit) on the new system, again with Window Builder and JavaFx.

When I open the workspace, I get errors saying there are missing "required libraries" -

```
com.ibm.icu_4.4.2.v20110823.jar
org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6.0.I20110111-0800.jar
org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.7.0.v20110110.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.0.v20110523.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.101.R37x_v20110810-1611.jar
org.eclipse.jface_3.7.0.v20110928-1505.jar
org.eclipse.jface.text_3.7.2.v20111213-1208.jar
org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.2.v20120110-1415.jar
org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.7.2.v3740f.jar
org.eclipse.text_3.5.101.v20110928-1504.jar
org.eclipse.ui.forms_3.5.101.v20111011-1919.jar
org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.7.1.v20120104-1859.jar
```

It is important to note that these libraries indeed **do not exist** in my new installation !

Can anyone help me resolve these issues ?

In answer to the two questions:

**Errors where ?** - In the problems pane of eclipse.  These libraries were added by eclipse when I originally built them, not by myself.

They are directly referenced in the project->Java Build Path->Libraries panel.

**How did I tranfert the projects ?** Well, since I don't use a version control system (*don't all scream at once*), they were simply "copied" over.
Is there a "better" way of doing this ?

Comment: The question is: how did you "transfer" your projects? Probably it is simply not a good idea to open the old workspace with a newer version of eclipse. In other words: normally your eclipse projects should be checked into your source code management system. You create a new checkout; and import those projects into your new eclipse (which is using a completely new workspace). Maybe it is possible to move whole workspaces, but I think that you will experience pain and frustration trying to do that.

Comment: There still isn't enough information. Are these projects Eclipse plug-ins?

Comment: These are "simple" ui based programs for parsing and transforming xml information into either a different file format, either a graphic representation (jpeg) of the data.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was as simple as, delete the offending library declarations !

The projects in question now build OK and run Ok.

Sorry for the waste of time.